# C# UserControl keyData Only working after pressing a button first in windows forms

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, user-controls

Buttons working fine as expected by clicking them.

**Issue:** When the UserControl is loaded for the first time and i didn't press any button in it, the Keydata are not working.
 After clicking a button manually the keybinds do work as intended. So obviously i would like to let the user use the keybind before any button press :
(I already tried to set focus on different elements such as the button itself)

```
 protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {

            switch (keyData)
            {
                case Keys.Enter:
                    button1.PerformClick();
                    return true;
                case Keys.Escape:
                    button2.PerformClick();
                    return true;
 }
      return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
```

i would like to let the user use the keydata before any button press :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Focused usercontrol, from main form button

```
private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
usercontrol11.BringToFront();
usercontrol11.Focus();
}
```